# How to inject a custom configuration processor into WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I have a pretty standard ASP.NET Core web app initialization code fragment in my Program.cs file:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            logging.AddSerilog(dispose: true);
        })
        .UseSerilog((ctx, config) => { config.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration); })
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

I would like to insert my custom configuration interceptor that reads and replaces the current final combined values of configuration, but I don't understand how to do that.

As we know from Microsoft docs, CreateDefaultBuilder overrides appsettings.json with environment-specific json, and finally overrides that with environment variables and command line args. I want to inject my custom code right after the last step, so I can intercept and modify values before they are passed further down to Startup with `public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }`.

I found an interesting function in the ASP.NET Core source code:

```
ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
```

that combines all the sources. I don't want to override it entirely, I just want to append my own config transformation after `ConfigureAppConfiguration` has done its job but before my Startup receives the configuration values.

How do I do that?

More information to give some context:

The goal is to inject custom decryption routines for config values that might be encrypted in any of those three places - appsettings.json, environment json, environment variables. I found only answers for implementing encryption for appsettings.json through custom config providers, but not for injecting my decryption routine AFTER all the combined sources.

I'm not asking for encryption/decryption routines themselves (I already have them) but for a solution for injecting my function calls that receive config values to overwrite with my decrypted values.

Comment: You can define custom extension method to transform configuration after it's being built. Or define custom configuration source, which was applied after all previous sources

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski  Could you please provide a simple example? Where do I inject it and how do I access all the configuration values before they get passed to Startup?

Answer (score 2):

if I get it right you want to have your `IConfiguration` by reading the original sources and decrypt them?

Then you can use something like this:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
                {
                    // Build an IConfiguration from the currently added IConfigurationSources
                    var notEncrypted = builder.Build();

                    // Clear the currently added ones
                    builder.Sources.Clear();

                    // Add you own IConfigurationSource with the previously added IConfiguration to read all values in the encrypted form.
                    var yourConfugurationSource = new < EncryptedConfigurationSource > (notEncrypted)

                    // Add your IConfigurationSource to the App 
                    // Now every call to IConfiguration takes your source
                    builder.Add(yourConfugurationSource);
                })
                .Build();
```

Just as a remark. The last added `IConfigurationSource` will be taken as first value. If this is enough you dont need to clear the automatically added `IConfigurationSource`s

Comment: Thank you, this one `builder.Build()` was the crucial step I was missing. I was looking at the wrong `ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) ` that has no access to the builder, so I could not get the latest values. Now it should work as expected.

Comment: Just for your information the ```config``` ```ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config)``` is the builder :)

Comment: My excitement was premature - I cannot get the values out of notEncrypted directly - there is one more additional component required for IConfigurationSource, which is Provider, and only that can access the values. However, the original notEncrypted has again all the collected providers and it gets tricky to understand, how to extract and replace the values.

Comment: Maybe you can do it also by not using ```ConfigureAppConfiguration``` and instead register your IConfiguration in the DI ```.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(sp => { notEncrypted = sp.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>(); return new < EncryptedConfiguration > (notEncrypted)); })```  But be sure the last IConfiguration is taken by the ```IServiceProvider```